# Ignore Greenkeeper notifications on a repository I watch?

Tags: notifications, github-issues

I'm watching a few GitHub repositories that each have a *lot* of dependencies. To assist managing all those dependencies, the owners of the repositories use [Greenkeeper](https://github.com/apps/greenkeeper), which creates a pull request whenever there's a new release of a dependency out. I watch the repositories so that I get notified of new discussions; those are what interest me. Greenkeeper pull requests do *not* interest me. Is there a way to somehow automatially ignore them?

I figured I might try blocking the Greenkeeper bot user, but I'm honestly not sure such a user exists. [The user "greenkeeper"](https://github.com/greenkeeper) is just a user, not attributed to any PRs; git commits from the bot say they're authored by "greenkeeper[bot]", [but that's just a 404](https://github.com/greenkeeper[bot]).

To be clear, I don't get email notifications from GitHub at all. I use GitHub's /notifications page instead, and I'm looking for a way to filter what shows up there. My current workaround is to click the "mute" button in the notification listing, which works but is a little inconvenient.

Comment: Worth noting that you can hide Greenkeeper from search results by using the syntax `-author:app/greenkeeper`. AFAIK, there's no way to apply this to your notifications (sadly), but it's still a handy related trick.